# Logging to seperate file in Apache NiFi Executescript processor (python)

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to log to a seperate file from ExecuteScript processor. I see that it logs to nifi-app.log and my logs gets lost easily.
I have tried logging module of python, but looks like the jython version used in nifi doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ExecuteStreamCommand`  processor. Encompass your logic from `ExecuteScript` into a Python script file and call it using `ExecuteStreamCommand` as `python3 my_script.py > log.txt`, this creates a separate log file.

Comment: That's correct. I could do that. But its to much code to port to executestreamcommand. As the current implementation gets and sets attributes to the flowfile. Yes, I could put the needed attributes in the args to the streamcommand processor and use evaluatejson to set the attributes post the streamcommand processor but as of now I wanted a way to log from executestream.